# Python Regex pattern match of a string

Tags: python, regex

What is the regex for a pattern in a string in:

```
description details #lo firstname lastname 29 March 2017
```

Therefore, there are four fields that regex needs to identify: description, priority, name and date.

I successfully matched the first string with:

```
^([^#]*).
```

But, I can't figure out how to match the other fields.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show what you've tried. Users would be more likely to help you if you show you've made an effort at solving your own problem

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Try [`^([^#]+)\s#(\w+)\s+(.*?)\s+(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$`](https://regex101.com/r/MVtswP/1)

Comment: The first name is caught but the last name is not. Also, what can I do if the month of the date is a string rather than a digit? Thank you very much @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may use

```
^(?P<description>[^#]+?)\s+#(?P<priority>\w+)\s+(?P<name>.*?)\s+(?P<date>\d.*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MVtswP/6)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (implicit if used with `re.match` / `re.fullmatch`)
- `(?P<description>[^#]+?)` - Group "description": one or more chars other than `#` as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `#` - a `#` char
- `(?P<priority>\w+)` - Group "priority" matching 1+ word chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?P<name>.*?)` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?P<date>\d.*)` - Group "date": a digit and the rest of the line
- `$` - end of string (implicit in `re.fullmatch`)

NOTE: `re.fullmatch` is available in Python 3.x.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Bd5U5p):

```
import re
rx = r"(?P<description>[^#]+?)\s+#(?P<priority>\w+)\s+(?P<name>.*?)\s+(?P<date>\d.*)$"
ss = ["description details #lo firstname lastname 2017-03-29", "description details #lo firstname lastname 2017 June 29"]
for s in ss:
    m = re.match(rx, s)
    if m:
        print(m.groupdict())
```

Output:

```
{'priority': 'lo', 'date': '2017-03-29', 'description': 'description details', 'name': 'firstname lastname'}
{'priority': 'lo', 'date': '2017 June 29', 'description': 'description details', 'name': 'firstname lastname'}
```